# spring mvc json Internal Server Error

Tags: spring-mvc

I have problem with returning JSON from controller with response body, i see that that hibernate make query to database but in moment of converting list to json i get in firebug Internal Server Error 500;

my servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<annotation-driven />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.daniluk.spotted.controller" />
<beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass">
        <beans:value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></beans:property>


</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

and controler with @ResponseBody

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/place")
public class PlaceControler {

@Autowired
private PlaceService placeService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Place> getAllPlaces() {

    return placeService.getAllPlaces();
}
```

}

any clues where i'm making mistake?

Comment: Any stack trace that you could post for the record ?

Comment: i have no errors in console, only in firebug

Comment: I'll try some guessing then: do you have the jackson jars in your classpath ? Did you try to state `produces = "application/json"` in your `@RequestMapping` ? Although none of these should lead to a `500 Internal Server Error` response code...

Comment: Try to see what's wrong with your logging, as it's very unlikely that a 500 response would not leave any trace in the logs...

Comment: `produces = "application/json"` doen't help, yes I have jackson mapper, but really in console i have only query to database

Comment: Did you try debugging then ? Set a breakpoint in DispatcherServlet.doDispatch()

Comment: does it matter where <mvc:annotation-driven /> is?

Comment: ok, in debuging errors showed in console but in second time, eclipse sometimes is surprising, error was with lazy fetching collection for json

Comment: did you use dependency jackson ?